# How to do rocket chat autologin in play application

Tags: rocket.chat

Hi I am new to Rocket chat

I need to auto login to rocket chat application from my application which build in playframework. I have tried iFrame  but I am getting bellow error.

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('http://chat.smb.sag.com:3000') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin ('http://smb.sag.com').

How to fix this issue